# Refactor several nested if with same else

Tags: if-statement, design-patterns, refactoring

This is not about an existing piece of code but I'm looking for some pattern that may exist in the case that some nested `if` perform the same thing in their `else` statement.

```
if(condition1(a)) {       
    doSomethingWith1(a);        
    if(condition2(a)) {
        doSomethingWith2(a);
    } else {
        elseFn();
    }    
} else {
    elseFn();
}
```

The `doSomethingWith...` functions are changing the value of `a`, making it complex to have all the condition in one `if`.

So I'm just wondering if there is a clearer way to write it (in C, if possible).

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case, looks like the first if, `if(condition1(a))`, is absolutely necessary to test for the value of `a` before calling `doSomethingWith1(a);` to avoid an exception. so, no, there is no other way to do it.

```
if(condition1(a)) {       
    doSomethingWith1(a);        
    if(condition2(a)) {
        doSomethingWith2(a);
    } else {
        elseFn();
    }    
} else {
    elseFn();
}
```

Comment: Of course there is another way to do it! There are _always_ alternatives with Boolean logic. For a broad example, see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws); for specific examples, see the other answers to this question. Also, why copy the question code into the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep a count of the "doSomethings" and invoke the elseFn unless all were executed.

```
int count = 0;
if (condition1(a)) {
    doSomethingWith1(a);
    count++;
    if (condition2(a)) {
        doSomethingWith2(a);
        count++;
        if (condition2(a)) {
            doSomethingWith2(a);
            count++;
        }    
    }    
}
if (count < 3) {
    elseFn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it more readable, though less efficient, to double-check the first condition. This refactoring eliminates nesting, without multiple functions. It also more clearly shows three distinct paths of execution by grouping each logical path into a single code block.

```
if (condition1(a) && condition2(a)) {       
    doSomethingWith1(a);
    doSomethingWith2(a);
}
else if (condition1(a)) {
    doSomethingWith1(a);
    elseFn();
}
else {
    elseFn();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know in C but in Java you could write this as the following:

```
void function(int a) {
boolean b1 = condition1(a);
if (b1) {
    doSomethingWith1(a);
    boolean b2 = condition2(a);
    if (b2) {
        doSomethingWith2(a);
    }
}

if (b1 || b2) {
    return;
}
elseFn();
}
```

Comment: `doSomethingWith2(a)` must not execute unless `condition1(a)` is true.

Comment: `elseFn()` must execute when `b1` is true and `b2` is false.